# How to do collection view cell "zoom in" and "zoom out" with image when we tapped on it in Ios

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am a beginner in iOS and in my project I have added a collection view programmatically and it was added successfully.
[image]

My requirement is when I click on UICollectionViewCell then it will be displayed full screen like below second image and when I click on close button image will go back to its actual position.

For this I have tried some code, but it's not working!

Please help me.

### My code:-

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    BOOL isFullScreen;
    CGRect prevFrame;
    UIImageView *dot;
    NSArray * images;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    images = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.png",@"2.png",@"3.png",@"4.png",@"5.png",@"6.png",@"7.png",@"8.png",@"9.png", nil];

    isFullScreen = NO;
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    _collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
    _collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 9;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width,cell.frame.size.height)];
    dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:dot];

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!isFullScreen) {

        [UICollectionView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{

            prevFrame = cell.frame;
            [cell setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            isFullScreen = TRUE;
        }];
        return;
    }

    else{

        [UICollectionView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            [cell setFrame:prevFrame];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            isFullScreen = FALSE;
        }];
        return;
    }
}
@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try
`cell.frame`will not give you the correct position of the cell on the screen, but the position within the content scrollview of the `CollectionViewController`

In order to find the correct frame, try

```
CGRect frameToAnimateTo = [self.navigationController.view convertRect:cell.frame fromView:self.collectionView];
```

To find the position of the cell view in the surrounding NavigationController.

As for the actual animation, it will be a bit more complicated than just transitioning views. Assuming you want to present the image in an own ViewController (which you don't necessarily have to, but your question indicates that you plan to...), you will have to implement a [custom ViewController transition](https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/view-controller-transitions/).

The easiest solution would be to develop a UIView with image view and button, that pops up from the collectionView and simply contains an UIImageView and an UIButton for closing.

Answer (score -2):

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)   {

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as! ViewController

    let imagenew = UIImage(named: iosImages[indexPath.row])
    print(imagenew!)
    vc.img = imagenew as Any as! UIImage 
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Send the image value to the next view controller and store that in the UIImage variable, then passed that value to the UIImageView for display.